# Checkbox inserted via append with javascript does not post data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

So I have this code in javascript wherein it inserts data into a table within a form input. Whenever i press on submit, it does nothing.

Javascript

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
$('.addtag').click(function() {
          var inputVal = document.getElementById("catinput").value;
  $("#tbl").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="'+inputVal+'" name="usertags[]" 
value="'+inputVal+'"></td><td> <label for="'+inputVal+'">'+inputVal+'</label><br/></td></tr>');
 });
})
</script>
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="publishchapter.php"  id="contentform" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<button type="submit" id="draft"   formaction="chapterpreview.php" ><?php echo $bid; ?>Preview</button>
 <button type="submit" id="publish" name="submit" value="Submit" >Publish</button>
 <span> Tags</span><br/> 
 <input id="catinput"/> <button type="button" class="addtag">Add</button><br/>
  <div class="c1f">
  <div class="c1"><table id="tbl" class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">

  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

All other inputs placed within the form does post but for some reason, any checkbox added to the table does not put out any post data
Here is the live website. [Sample website](https://novelwonderland.com/addchapter.php?bid=57hc1h8xe7pifnzi6w5mzeeo9bdu29g318su0gphg3j6cphj7e8p10rzidsna5x1b7e7sufgspj155ne2dq3wx5rxke6292t7e6h)

edit: This one does equate to adding or appending a new row to a table. The code here works already in adding a new row to the table via javascript. But once it is posted to another page, it does not post data whatsoever and it is just blank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery - how to append input with name array to a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705137/jquery-how-to-append-input-with-name-array-to-a-row)

Comment: It does not. The code above can already append the row. My qualms about it is that it does not post to another page.